# black screen when starting my laptop but then appears when it logs to windows

Tags: windows-7, boot, display, graphics-card

when i turn on my laptop, the screen is black. However it turns back on when it logs to windows and works fine (win7 64 bits). Unfortunately I cannot format my laptop since the screen is black in the beginning. How do i solve the problem? I clicked on microsoft problems and it found 39 errors saying "graphic hardware problem". 
I uninstalled my graphic card driver (Nvidia ge force go 7600) and installed it again, still didnt work!

Comment: More information about the detected problems is required to help

Comment: Highly possible that you have enabled the Quick Boot option from the BIOS if the option is there. But it should show the Windows Logo in that case. Graphics might be the source. What about the BIOS? Can you get into the bios?

Answer (score 2):

More info would be nice, but try these steps.

1) When you switch ON your computer, start tapping the "F8" key to get

"Windows Advanced Options"( if boot menu appears, press "Esc" key and

keep tapping the F8 key)

2) Select the option "Last Known Good Configuration".

If the problem still exists then follow the step 1 and this time select the option

"Safe Mode". Check if you are able to boot into Safe Mode.

One question, is your laptop a Dell?

Comment: ok ill add more details:

Comment: my laptop is a toshiba satellite a100.

Comment: more infos: I used to have a geforce 7300 (128mb) graphic card installed cause the original one (geforce go7600 256mb) burned out. now the geforce 7300 didnt work well recently so i bought the original geforce go7600 graphic cards. i updated the graphic driver to match the one i have. everything was good until last week, when i turn the laptop (toshiba staellite pro A100) black screen at the beginning until it enters the windows desktop and everything seems ok.

Comment: i connected it to an external display, still the same thing, black screen in the beginning but then ok when it eneters windows. the problem is, when i start my laptop, even when i press f8 to enter the bios or boot mode, the screen stays black although i know it entered the boot mode cause the screen stays black! so i restarted the laptop and didnt press any key, still black screen until it enters windows desktop!!!

Answer (score 1):

try again connectiong another screen in the VGA, then press FN+F5, this combination will change the connection location.
the 2nd monitor should now work.

omegalfa

Answer (score 0):

Try to start the laptop putting some monitor on the vga output of the laptop if there is some signal there and try to install from that point.

Comment: I tried that, it stays also black on the external display, and then appear normal when it enters windows desktop